# Subscribe inside a Subscribe repeating multiple times

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, angularfire

I have an observable that outputs an array on subscribe

```
appleProducts.subscribe((snap) => {
   console.log(snap);
});

iphone.subscribe((snap) => { 
   console.log(snap); 
});
```

> console output:
>
> > [ipad, iphone, mac]
> >
> > [iphone4, iphone5, iphone6]

---

Theose two subscribes are executing asyncronously. however, I need to get appleProducts before iphone, so when I put `iphone.subscribe` function inside `appleProducts.subscribe` function, something wierd happens:

```
appleProducts.subscribe((snap) => {
   console.log(snap);
   iphone.subscribe((snap) => { 
      console.log(snap);
   });
});
```

> console output:
>
> > [ipad, iphone, mac]
> >
> > [iphone4]
> >
> > [iphone4, iphone5]
> >
> > [iphone4, iphone5, iphone6]

---

Does anyone understand why this is happening? Thanks

Comment: Is there a dependency between the two observables? Meaning do you need output from the first one to trigger the second one? Doesn't look like it from the code you're showing, but just confirming since it will change the answer. If it's just about order then @BeetleJuice has the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using AngularFire2 ? if yes then it's related to Firebase list issue.
they're working on it

see this https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/574

Answer (score 1):

To get results from one observable all before results from the next, use the [instance operator `concat`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concat)

```
appleProducts.concat(iphone).subscribe(...)
```

The subscription will first output the results of the first observable. Once that completes, it will output the results of the second.

You could get the same result by using the [static method `concat`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-concat)

```
Observable.concat(appleProducts, iPhone).subscribe(...)
```

Comment: @ArielGelbard could you doublecheck: if you simply do `iphone.subscribe(...)`, you get a single array printed?

Comment: yup, I triple checked, it is not working...its subscribed to the firebase observable ex."this.angularfire.database.list(appleProductsObjectURL).subscribe("

Comment: @ArielGelbard OK.  Your OP gave the impression that the simple subscribe worked, but that things broke down when you tried to order results. If even the simple `iphone.subscribe(...)` is not working, that's where you will probably find the root of the problem, rather than in the ordering of results.

Comment: concat only calls the first attribute 'appleProducts', it doesn't call 'iPhone' as well...

Answer (score 0):

So after being lead to the 'concat' function of rxjs, I looked into other things like 'forkJoin' (which didn't work), and I found my solution with '[merge](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/merge.md)'

Sample Code Solution:

```
var source = Rx.Observable.merge(
    appleProducts,
    iphone);

var subscription = source.subscribe(
    function (x) {
        console.log('Next: ' + x);
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    },
    function () {
        console.log('Completed');
    });
```

> console output:
>
> > [ipad, iphone, mac]
> >
> > [iphone4, iphone5, iphone6]

Comment: Beware: `merge` does not guarantee that results from one source will arrive before results from the other; it just outputs data as it arrives. So if order is important to you (it was your stated objective), you may be setting yourself up for a headache later.

Comment: yes you are right, order is important to me, what do you suggest instead?